# Checking values of context variables in Django custom template tag block

Tags: django, templates, variables, tags

I'm trying to write a custom template tag in Django that will do the following:

- get all context variables between the start and end tags
- if all variables have a valid, non-empty value (i.e., not `None` or `''`), return the entire block
- otherwise (if any variable is empty), return an empty string (so nothing gets rendered)

I realize that I could use `{% if var1 and var2 and var3 ... and varN %}`, but I'd rather have a custom tag that does it so I don't have to double-check the `if` statement every single time I change something.

This is my current code:

in template_helpers.py:

```
@register.tag(name="iff")
def iff(parser,token):
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endiff',))
    parser.delete_first_token()
    return IffNode(nodelist)

def do_all_exist(context):
    sendback = True
    for var in context:
        if (var is None) or (var == ''):
            sendback = False
        if not sendback:
            break
        else:
            continue
    return sendback

class IffNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self,nodelist):
        self.nodelist = nodelist
    def render(self,context):
        if do_all_exist(context):
            return context
        else:
            return ''
```

in template.html:

```
{% load template_helpers %}
...
{% for term in terms %}
<div class="entry">
     <p class="definition">
           <big><b>{{ term.word }}</b></big>
           <br /><b>{{ term.part_of_speech }}:</b> {{ term.definition }}
     </p>

     {% iff %}
           <p class="etymology">from: {{ term.etymology }}</p>
     {% endiff %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
...
```

Right now, the `iff` block is empty whether or not there's a valid value in `term.etymology`. It shouldn't be checking the value of every entry's etymology, because `iff` is inside `for`. But I am lost on how to check the context variables.

Comment: it is kind of too much for a template tag. you should do the logic in views and render the data to template

Comment: You'll need to parse out all tags in the block, and calculate free vs. bound variables, then check the free variables at the top level. I've done something similar at https://github.com/datakortet/dk-template where I'm trying to find all variables used by the template that haven't been defined by the view. The code is pretty rough, but it might give you some ideas. (if you're just concerned about `{{ values }}` the problem is much easier..)

Answer (score 0):

You are over-complicate your process. You should do it in your views method:

```
# this is the context you currently have
context = {foo: bar, baz: test}
# check if all context have values
do_all_exist = all(context.values())
# add the result to the context
context['do_all_exist'] = do_all_exist
# return the context with your HttpResponse
```

Then in your template:

```
{% if do_all_exist %}
    <p class="etymology">from: {{ term.etymology }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making things more difficult than they are. I think, this is too much for a template tag.

why dont you just do this?

```
{% if term.etimology %}
    <p class="etymology">from: {{ term.etymology }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: @ShangWang @doniyor Sure, but I don't want to check if all the possible context variables exist. I want to only check the ones inside the iff block. For example, if I want to print flags if and only if they exist for an entry, using this `all_exist` wouldn't work for entries that have flags but not an etymology.

Comment: @JensenStroup if I undertood you correctly... updated my answer

Comment: Right, but I want the tag to check the entire block. A lot of times I have five or six variables in my `if` block... and I don't want it to suddenly not print because I took out one of those variables. But, I mean, I *can* do it that way... it's just going to be a pain to make sure my if statement always has exactly the right tags for the block.

Comment: I don't think you could achieve that without `if` statement, unless what are you trying to render inside `if` is identical for all variables.